# Snowflake JS SP - bind variables in create view workaround

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello Snowflake Heroes,
do you know of any viable workaround for a current limitation in snowflake JS stored procedures which is that one cannot use bind variables in create view inside a stored procedure? Here is the code that is not working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAKE_VIEW(V2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS $$
snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "\
create or replace view TEST_VIEW as \
(with cte as (select COLUMN1 FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) \
select * from cte where COLUMN1 < ?) \
",binds:[V2] }).execute()
return 1.0
$$;
call MAKE_VIEW(2);
```

error message:

```
002210 (0A000): Execution error in store procedure MAKE_VIEW:
SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 64
Bind variables not allowed in view and UDF definitions.
At Statement.execute, line 2 position 119
```

Kind regards

**update 1:**
what I would like to achieve is to have a view that has values behind bind variables in its definition rather than variables themselves, namely this:

```
create or replace view TEST_VIEW as \
(with cte as (select COLUMN1 FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) \
select * from cte where COLUMN1 < 2)
```

I would like to have things set up this way ( SP passing variables to views and creating them) becuase I need the views to be created using an output from another SP in a bind variable, namely something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAKE_VIEW(V2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS $$

X=snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "call myOtherSP(?)",binds:[V2]}).execute()
X.next();
Y=X.getColumnValue(0)[0];

snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "\
create or replace view TEST_VIEW as \
(with cte as (select COLUMN1 FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) \
select * from cte where COLUMN1 < ?) \
",binds:[Y] }).execute()
return 1.0
$$;
call MAKE_VIEW(2);
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a view that then has bind variables in it - or are you trying to replace the bind variables with actual values before the view is created? If it's the first option - then this is nothing to do with JS, you can't create a view with bind variables in it, regardless of the mechanism that you are using to create the view. Please can you update your question with what you expect the DDL for the view to be once it has been created?

Comment: Thank you for your answer NickW, I need the values behind the bind variables in views definitions, i updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build your CREATE VIEW with the actual values, not with bind variables; the way you have constructed it at the moment it is attempting to include the bind parameters in the View definition, which won't work (and is not, I think, what you are trying to achieve).

Try something like this:

```
sqlText: "\
create or replace view TEST_VIEW as \
(with cte as (select COLUMN1 FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) \
select * from cte where COLUMN1 < '" + Y + "'"
```

Comment: this works, thanks a lot  - do you happen to know how to cast the Y into float, because using this syntax results in Y being a string in view definition.
edit - ok removing single quotation marks makes Y a number, namely 
[...] < " + Y + ""

Answer (score 1):

Using JS string interpolation to embed parameter values:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MAKE_VIEW(V2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS $$
snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: `
create or replace view TEST_VIEW as 
with cte as (select COLUMN1 FROM VALUES (1),(2),(3) ) 
select * from cte where COLUMN1 < ${V2}`}).execute();

return 1.0;
$$;

call MAKE_VIEW(3);
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_VIEW;
-- 1
-- 2
```

Notes:

1. It could cause SQL Injection if parameters are not trusted/sanitized
2. When passing dates/other values as text it is advisable to explicitly cast:

   ```
   COLUMN1 = try_to_date( '${V2}', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
   ```