# Binding value in SHOW USER statement using JS in Snowflake Stored Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

It looks like Snowflake doesn't process parameter binding for `SHOW USER` statements in JS like this.

```
var sql_cmd = "SHOW USERS LIKE ?;";
var username = "user.name"
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_cmd, binds:[username]});
var users = stmt.execute();
```

It just gives me an error saying that

```
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 16 unexpected '?'. At Statement.execute, line 14 position 18
```

1. How do I make it work?
2. Is there a more accurate docs on what is supported by the `binds` feature? I feel like it should support all SQLs but looks like it doesn't work on `CREATE` either on another thread I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456342/snowflake-js-sp-bind-variables-in-create-view-workaround).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this as an alternative? Note to use the SHOW USERS command you must execute the proc as a CALLER: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-rights.html#caller-s-rights-stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_bind(username VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
 var sql_command = "SHOW USERS LIKE '" + USERNAME + "'";
 var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} ); 

var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next();
return result1.getColumnValue(1);
$$
;
```

alternatively you dont need a parameter and you could just use the variable within the SP

```
 var username= 'USER1';
 var sql_command = "SHOW USERS LIKE '" + username + "'";
```

call the stored proc

```
CALL user_bind ('USER1'); --or 
CALL user_bind ();
```

Comment: Thanks, Paul. But I'm really looking for a solution with `bind`. Or if you have a recommended way of sanitising the input, can you share that as well?

Comment: If you are open to using the ACCOUNT_USAGE views, you can use a bind variable with the users table, although there is a delay with that view being populated: 

var sql_cmd = "SELECT * FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.USERS WHERE NAME LIKE ?";